# Accessing docker volume on win 10

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins

On a Windows 10 OS, I am running docker for Linux Container for running JenKins.

I have run following cmd

> docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v
>   jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts

This created a volume jenkins_home. I am not sure how to access this in docker? And can I access the files created in this volume outside docker (directly from Windowns)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to access named volumes like this is by mounting them into containers.  The process in the container you launched would actually see the volume contents in `/var/jenkins_home`, for instance; you could mount the volume into other containers as well.  Docker's [documentation on basic data maintenance for named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) suggests this path, for example.

If you specifically need to access the data on the host you should use a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) rather than a named volume.  You will control which host directory gets used inside the container.

(I will acknowledge that, on Linux, processes with root that are willing to dig inside Docker internals can probably readily find the actual underlying storage, but this isn't recommended and isn't portable to other host OSes or storage drivers.)

Comment: Okay, I get it. Will try with bind mount. Where can I find bind mound commands for windows?

Comment: docker run -v C:\Users\SomeUser\data:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts works on windows